# Postman. Issue with multipart/form-data (415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, multipartform-data

I got some issue during test my endpoint (with *multipart/form-data*) on Postman.

I have following method (some fields + photo). This method works with Swagger ok.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> MailPhoto([FromForm] MailwithPhoto mailWithPhoto)
{...}

public class MailwithPhoto 
{ 
  public string mail_message { get; set; } 
  public IFormFile photo_file { get; set; }
  public string userContact { get; set; }
  public string category { get; set; }
  public string userName { get; set; }
  public string method { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x3s7.gif)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First need to change Key `message` to `mail_message`,or `mail_message` will not be binded.
415 is often due to Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

Here is a working demo(I use a .net core mvc project):
[image]

[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wil try it and report.